# Poisson point process in "input" to another Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have a Poisson point process with rate $\lambda$. I want to consider a new process that fires an event every time the Poisson point process finds 3 points. How this process can be described? What is the event rate and the variance of this process?

I put on evidence that the second process is not simply a Poisson point process with rate $\frac{\lambda}{3}$.

Comment: The process can be described by $M(t)=\lfloor\frac13N(t)\rfloor$ where $N(t)$ denotes the original Poisson process.

Comment: Thanks @drhab. How can I estimate the variance of $M(t)$?

Comment: I made an effort to calculate its mean on base of:$$\mathbb{E}\lfloor\frac{1}{3}N\left(t\right)\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left(N\left(t\right)=3k\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left(N\left(t\right)=3k+1\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left(N\left(t\right)=3k+2\right)$$But that appeared to be quite hard and seems to require calculations of the sort $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{kx^{k}}{(3k+i)!}$ for $i=0,1,2$. I gave up (too much work and not easy). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3529254/75923) you can find a question I posed about it. The answers are nice.

Comment: [...]Maybe you can do an effort yourself. Finding variance will be even more difficult I think.

Answer (score 0):

Denote this process by $X(t)$. The interarrival distribution has $\mathrm{Erlang}(3,\lambda)$ distribution with density $f_J(t) = \lambda\frac{(\lambda t)^2}2 e^{-\lambda t}$. The Laplace-Stieltjes transform of this distribution is
\begin{align}
\hat F(z) &= \mathbb E[e^{-zJ}]\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-zt}\lambda\frac{(\lambda t)^2}2 e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf dt\\ 
&= \frac{\lambda^3}{(\lambda+z)^3}.
\end{align}
Let $M(t) = \mathbb E[X(t)]$ be the renewal function. Then the Laplace-Stieltjes transform of $M$ is
\begin{align}
\hat M(z) = \frac{\hat F(z)}{1-\hat F(z)} = \frac{\frac{\lambda^3}{(\lambda+z)^3}}{1-\frac{\lambda ^3}{(\lambda +z)^3}} = \frac{\lambda ^3}{z^3+3 \lambda  z^2+3 \lambda ^2 z}.
\end{align}
Inversion yields
$$
M(t) = \frac{1}{3} \lambda  \left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{2} (3 \lambda  t)} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \lambda  t\right)+\cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \lambda  t\right)\right)\right).
$$
From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195797/formula-for-the-variance-of-a-renewal-process) we can derive the variance of a renewal process from the renewal function:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X(t)) &= 2\int_0^t M(t-s)\ \mathsf d M(s) + M(t) - M(t)^2\\
&=2\int_0^t \frac{\lambda ^3}{3 \lambda ^2 (t-s)+3 \lambda  (t-s)^2+(t-s)^3}\left(-\frac{3 \lambda ^3}{(\lambda +s)^4}\right)\ \mathsf ds\\
&\quad+\frac{1}{3} \lambda  \left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{2} (3 \lambda  t)} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \lambda  t\right)+\cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \lambda  t\right)\right)\right)\\
&\quad - \left(\frac{1}{3} \lambda  \left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{2} (3 \lambda  t)} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \lambda  t\right)+\cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \lambda  t\right)\right)\right)\right)^2.
\end{align}
Unfortunately, I can't get Mathematica to evaluate the integral. There isn't likely to be a nice closed form for this one.